# Разница между последовательными элементами массива

Tags: c#

Определить какие два последовательных элемента массива наименее отличаются дpуг от
дpуга. Hайти индекс пеpвого элемента паpы.
Код вроде как написан правильно, но ответ всегда выдает один,просьба помочь)

```
int raznica = Math.Abs(massiv[0] - massiv[1]);                 //Решение самой задачи
        int element = raznica;
        for (int i = 0; i < massiv.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i+1; j < massiv.Length; j++)
            {
                if (Math.Abs(massiv[i]-massiv[j]) < raznica)
                {
                    raznica = Math.Abs(massiv[i] - massiv[j]);
                    element = i;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Зачем Вам второй цикл?

Comment: @PetSerAl, чтобы найти элемент с минимальной разницей :)

Comment: @Grundy А зачем тогда первый цикл?

Comment: @PetSerAl, чтобы `i` тоже менялось

Comment: `Код вроде как написан правильно, но ответ всегда выдает один` для одних и тех же данных будет один и тот же ответ.

Comment: в общем, убирайте второй цикл и сравнивайте элементы с индексами `i` и `i+1`, и `element` в начале инициализируйте нулем а не разницей